# C# inherited ArrayList class with custom method to query itself

Tags: c#

I have a C# class that inherits `System.Collections.ArrayList`, which is defined as this:

```cs
namespace foo
{

    public class ConnectionTracker : System.Collections.ArrayList
    {

        public void RemoveConnection(Connection connectionToRemove)
        {

            // Remove from global track object
            this.Remove(connectionToRemove);

            // Remove trusted host from another class
            External.RemoveAotherHost(connectionToRemove.Name);

        }

    }

}
```

This class is not used within a C# application, rather within PowerShell.  A new instance of this class is constructed and used to track web application connections.

```bsh
$GlobalVariable = [foo.ConnectionTracker]::new()
$Globalvariable.Add([foo.Connection]::new($ConstructorPropertyValues1)
$Globalvariable.Add([foo.Connection]::new($ConstructorPropertyValues2)
```

The web application connection has a property called `Default`, which is of type `Bool`.  I want to create a method that searches all members within itself for the only entry that contains a `true` value for `Default`.

I have attempted to add the following:

```cs
public Connection Default()
{

    var defaultConnection = from Connection c in this
                            where c.Default == true
                            select c;

    return defaultConnection.Single();

}
```

But within PowerShell, I get this error:

```bsh
C:\> $GlobalVariable.Default()
MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "Default" with "0" argument(s): "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Management.Automation.PSObject' to type 'Connection'."
```

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?  Yes, I already know that I could do `$GlobalVariable | Where-Object { $_.Default }`.  But I would rather build a class method that handles this in an easier way.

Comment: It seems like the error is that it doesn't know what to do with the return value of `Default`. What do you want to do with that? Assign it to a variable? Pretty print it?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your class (take a look at https://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/04/08/basics-of-writing-a-powershell-module-with-c-part-2-debugging/). My guess is that PowerShell is wrapping your Connection objects with a PSObject, and that's what you are collecting. You're likely better off making everything more PowerShell-like, and less C#-like (have a New-MyConnection command and command that collect and manipulate the objects that it generates)

Comment: @JamesFaix just return the object it is, which is of type `[foo.Connection]`.